# How can i call NStimer form one viewcontroller from unother viewcontroller?

Tags: iphone

At first time i call the timer like this in Third viewcontroller

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then timer called the targetMethod

```
-(void)targetMethod
{
 First * sVC = [[First alloc] initWithNibName:@"First" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
 [self presentModalViewController:sVC animated:YES];
 [sVC release];
 [timer invalidate];
}
```

First viewcontroller opened..
In First viewcontroller had one button.In button action
i wrote

```
- (IBAction) Action:(id)sender
{
 [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; 
 Third *BVC=[[Third alloc]init];
    [Bvc TimerStart];       //Timestart is function i start timer in this function..
 //i want to call Third  viewcontroller timer function this place
}
```

timer started..But view didn't open (first )viewcontroller.......

Please help me......

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do with this BVC object or what the point of that method is. Can you explain further?

Answer (score 1):

Bala,

Place the NSTimer object in the App Delegate .h file, include that .h file in wherever you use the timer.  This will allow the NSTimer to be a global timer which you can call from any other view that includes the app delegate header file.

In app delegate .h file (in the appropriate areas):

```
NSTimer *delayTimer;

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer *delayTimer;
```

Synthesize this in the app delegate .m file (remember to release it in dealloc):

```
@synthesize delayTimer;
```

Then in whichever views you use the timer in, access it like this:

```
// get global variable
SomeNameHereAppDelegate *mainDelegate = (SomeNameHereAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];    

mainDelegate.delayTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(targetMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
```

Then when you want to invalidate it from somewhere, you just do this:

```
[mainDelegate.delayTimer invalidate];
 mainDelegate.delayTimer = nil;
```

Answer (score 0):

What if if i need to have a count down timer which should be shared among the view controllers.do i have to make it in the app delegate where the remaining seconds could be an ivar also in app delegate with property?
In this case i would post notification from the timer handler after updating the remaining seconds

Comment: i solved the issue by saving the endtimestamp of the timer to nsuserdefaults when i start the timer first time.When a viewcontroller loads its view it reads the endtimesamp from the user defaults and start its own timer according to the remaining time.

Answer (score 0):

In AppDelegate.h

```
@property int timePassed;
```

In AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize timePassed;
```

In ViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)NSTimer *timer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *time;
```

In ViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.timePassed = 180;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(TimePasses) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];;
}


-(void) TimePasses{
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
delegate.timePassed = delegate.timePassed - 1;
NSLog(@"TimePasses %d", delegate.timePassed);
int minuts = delegate.timePassed / 60;
int seconds = delegate.timePassed - (minuts * 60);

NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
time.text = timerOutput;
}
```

In SecondViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)NSTimer *timer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *time;
```

In SecondViewController.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(TimePasses) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];;
}

-(void) TimePasses{
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate*) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSLog(@"TimePasses in 2 %d", delegate.timePassed);
int minuts = delegate.timePassed / 60;
int seconds = delegate.timePassed - (minuts * 60);

NSString *timerOutput = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2d:%.2d", minuts, seconds];
time.text = timerOutput;
}
```