# adding subview to different class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, nstimer

I am making a test app. Right now I have a timer in the application `didFinishLaunching`.

Here is my code:

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {     timelabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 80, 280, 120)];    
[self.view addSubview:timelabel];
[timelabel.text isEqualToString:@"0"];
time = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self     
  selector:@selector(timervoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 }


-(void)timervoid {
int now;
now = [timelabel.text intValue];
int after;
after = now + 1;
timelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", after];

 }
```

I need the timer to continue through all classes, which is why I put it in the app delegate application `didFinishLaunching`, but how can I add it to the class's view?

Comment: This Link might be of some use to u... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959641/how-can-i-call-nstimer-form-one-viewcontroller-from-unother-viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use UIApplication sharedApplication to access the timer which u have declared in the appDelegate class.

Hope this helps

Happy Coding !